# Dockerfile VOLUME definition to mount project tree

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to automate creation of dev environment and deployment using Docker. Here is my minimal example of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM java
VOLUME .:/hello
```

and build it as

```
docker build -t hello-server .
```

Then i run image `hello-server`, visit it's `/hello` directory, it exists, but is empty.

But when I run image using

```
docker run -i -t -v $(pwd):/hello2 hello-server
```

`/hello2` contains README, Dockerfile and other files of the project. How to properly define volume mounting from Dockerfile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't work:

```
VOLUME .:/hello
```

You can't specify the host directory for a volume in a Dockerfile. The reason is that it would be non-portable.

Either copy the files into the image with `COPY` or just mount the volume at run-time as you have been doing.

Comment: It seems VOLUME in Dockerfile is useless. I can `docker run -v hostdir:containerdir` to mount the host dir.

Comment: It's far from useless, you just can't specify the host directory, so files will be placed in a directory on the host controlled by Docker.